# How would I show combinatorically that for all positive integers $n$, $ n \binom{2n-1}{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k}^2$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, combinations

I have tried using the binomial theorem and various identities associated to prove this combinatorically but I seem to be getting stuck somewhere. At this point I think the only way this can be done is breaking down both $ n \binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k}^2$ as follows:
$$ n \binom{2n-1}{n-1} = n\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!(n-1)}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k}^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n-1}{k}2^{n-1}$$

Then follow something like this proof(not exactly this but formatting wise):
Both sides count the number of ways to choose a
committee among n people, then to choose a president from the committee.
On the left-hand side, we first choose a k-member committee in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways,
then we choose its president in k ways.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated... thank you for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\sum_{k=0}^n k{n\choose k}^2 = {n{2n-1\choose n-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042461/prove-sum-k-0n-kn-choose-k2-n2n-1-choose-n-1)

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect! I don’t know how I’m so bad at finding already answered questions...